# PHP Function that is always looping even without human intervention

Tags: php, html

I have a php code that deals with mapping markers in a google maps, and the coordinates needed are fetched from a certain data storage platform. My problem now is that the coordinates are always updating and when I run the php code it will only read the last entry of the coordinates. Is there a php function that allows a perpetual loop for the code even without opening the php code itself?

**EDIT**

**This the php code is for the map plotter**

```
<?
php
session_start();
require ("trial.php");
 ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table><col width="500px">
<tr>
    <td>
    <div id="map" style="height: 500px; width: 100%;">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var locations = [
          ['Time', <?php echo $_SESSION["latitude"]?>, <?php echo $_SESSION["longitude"]?>, 1]
        ];
        alert(locations[6][2]);
        document.write(locations[6]);
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 17,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.5843976,120.9762802),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker, i;
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));
        }
    </script>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is the php code for the fetching**

```
<?php 
$_SESSION["longitude"] = file_get_contents("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/Chann‌​el_ID/fields/1/last.‌​txt"); 
$_SESSION["latitude"] = file_get_contents("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/Chann‌​el_ID/fields/2/last.‌​txt"); 
?>
```

Comment: So change the PHP code to get more information each time it askes for it

Comment: is it an api? if so post your code and let us have a peek.

Comment: The coordinates is only updated once every 15 seconds, thus I can only fetch one data every 15 seconds

Comment: `<?php     
$_SESSION["longitude"] = file_get_contents("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/Channel_ID/fields/1/last.txt");
$_SESSION["latitude"] = file_get_contents("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/Channel_ID/fields/2/last.txt");
?>`

Comment: This code, named **trial.php**, is for retrieving the coordinates from thingspeak

Answer (score 0):

I just have asked this question to a friend of mine. And he says I could just use a `cron` or `cron job`. And I will just research more into this function.

Comment: I'd agree with using a cron job. Personally, I choose to recoded similar program into python scripts and used "from tendo import singleton
me = singleton.SingleInstance()". That way only one cron job runs at once - and I don't need to spin up a whole web server to run it.

Comment: I'll remember that since I'm also dealing with python scripts for this project.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.